# Can't restart infinite animation using ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

Can't restart infinite animation using ObjectAnimator. Below code doen't work as expected, my ImageView is always stays not animated. When I remove `if else` statements, animation works good. Any suggestions?

```
private var progressAnimation: ObjectAnimator? = null

private fun setProgressAnimation(start: Boolean){
    if (start) {
        progressAnimation =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.imageProgress, "rotation", 0f, 180f).apply {
                duration = 1600
                repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
                interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
                start()
            }
    } else progressAnimation?.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to have the object animator null, and then re-create it every time the value is passed in as true?  I wonder if this wouldn't fix things (I don't have currently have an open project with databinding xml layouts to test with):

```
private val progressAnimation: ObjectAnimator = 
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.imageProgress, "rotation", 0f, 180f).apply {
    duration = 1600
    repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
}

private fun setProgressAnimation(start: Boolean){
    when(start) {
        true -> if(!progressAnimation.isStarted) progressAnimation.start()
        false -> if(progressAnimation.isStarted) progressAnimation.cancel()
    }
}
```

Here I am not re-creating the animator every time the method is called, and only calling `.start()` when the method is called with "true" and it's not already running, as well as only calling `.cancel()` if the animation is running when passed "false".

Edit:
So the reason to not just create the single val is the accessibility of the binding.  I have created the dummy starter project in Android studio, and this is the entire code for one of the two fragments where this animation is toggled on and off (it is controlled by the "next" button and animates the text, but should start / stop your progress image animation from any event you want):

```
/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass as the default destination in the navigation.
 */
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var progressAnimation: ObjectAnimator


    private fun setProgressAnimation(start: Boolean){
        when(start) {
            true -> if(!progressAnimation.isStarted) progressAnimation.start()
            false -> if(progressAnimation.isStarted) progressAnimation.cancel()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        progressAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.textviewFirst, "rotation", 0f, 180f).apply {
            duration = 1600
            repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        }
        binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener {
            setProgressAnimation(!progressAnimation.isStarted)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

If you wanted to start , pause, resume instead, removing the private function and adding this code to your event trigger does the trick:

```
binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener {
                when {
                    progressAnimation.isPaused -> progressAnimation.resume()
                    !progressAnimation.isStarted -> progressAnimation.start()
                    progressAnimation.isRunning || progressAnimation.isStarted -> progressAnimation.pause()
                    else -> progressAnimation.cancel()
                }
        }
```

If you really want to keep the function, and say you wanted to pause and resume, or start cancel (whatever the need may be) you could also change this function to something like this (you can call these animation methods from separate control flow statements if needed, and not be tied to a true/false option):

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    progressAnimation =
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.textviewFirst, "rotation", 0f, 180f).apply {
            duration = 1600
            repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        }
    binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener {
        when {
            progressAnimation.isPaused -> animateTheThing { progressAnimation.resume() }
            !progressAnimation.isStarted -> animateTheThing { progressAnimation.start() }
            progressAnimation.isRunning || progressAnimation.isStarted -> animateTheThing { progressAnimation.pause() }
            else -> animateTheThing { progressAnimation.cancel() }
        }
    }
}

private fun animateTheThing(animationAction: () -> Unit) {
    animationAction.invoke()
}
```

Comment: `.start()` and `.cancel()` or `.pause()` doesn't work with infinite animation, please check

Comment: .start() and .cancel() both work on that animation.

Comment: Do you use here png or vector drawable to animate?

Comment: I used the default text field on screen from the dummy project.  Just added an ImageView with an imported png, and rotated that as well.  If you are noticing the weird visual effect change your 180f to 360f in ObjectAnimator.ofFloat() so that you get a full rotation.  I'm not sure what the image is or what the desired outcome / effect of the animation is specifically based on the code you posted.

Comment: Vector drawables are not animated for me by that way

Comment: There's likely something else wrong with your application code then (you haven't posted the xml, or the activity / fragment code).  I just added a vector drawable, animates just fine.  You can create a blank new app in Android Studio (the two fragment option), add an ImageView to your first fragment, load a vector drawable into that ImageView, and update the fragment with the code from my answer (just point to your image view instead of binding.textviewFirst) and watch a vector drawable in an ImageView spin around on the button click.

Comment: If you want to just animate the vector drawable, start [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable) and [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/drawable-animation)